# SSIS Project Level Connection Manager Property configurations

Tags: configuration, ssis, ssis-2012

I have just started looking at using the SSIS 2012 Project Deployment. One thing I have noticed is that once the project is deployed all the properties relating to the project level connection manager get deployed too and hence need to be configured (Linked to SSIS Environment Variables).

Was just wondering whether the SSIS environment is smart enough to infer the ConnectionString property from the InitialCatalog and ServerName properties. That way I would only need InitialCatalog and ServerName Environment Variables and not a third variable containing the actual connection string which would result in a duplicate configuration.

Please see screenshot below showing an example of this.

[image]

Comment: Or you can use 1 Environment variable which is the whole `ConnectionString` and forget messing with the parts.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want to set the initial catalog and server name property paramatically.

Here are the steps to do it: [Applicable for SSIS 2005 and above]

**Step-1**: Create two variable in SSIS package (Package scope) and name them DbName, ServerName

[image]

**Step-2**: In connection manager, create a OLEDB connection and test connection.

**Step-3**: Now, right click on the connection manager and click properties.

**Step-4**: In properties, click expression. You will see below window. In this window select initial catalog

[image]

**Step-5**: Now click on expression and drag drop DbName (i.e. your catalog name) variable from upper left window to expression text box and evaluate it.

[image]

**Step-6**: Do the same for Server name. and you are done

> Remember: If your initial catalog and database parameter name are not
>   correct then you may face connection issue.

**Other way, Specifically for SSIS 2012 and above**

Now, as you have mentioned SSIS2012. Let;s utilize its feature of [Project parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213214(v=sql.110).aspx)

- Create project level variables, You can either create two variable names [DBName, ServerName] or complete connection string.

[image]

- Create OLEDB connection in connection manager and right click on the connection. Then select, "`Parameterize`"
- Based on your parameter, you can set parameter to properties like Initial catalog, Server Name, Connection string etc. Or you can create project level parameter from here by selecting appropriate values, as shown below

[image]

Read this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/16/configuring-projects-and-packages-using-parameters.aspx) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! If I say only parameterise the ServerName and InitialCatalog properties of the project level connection manager, will the ConnectionString property be inferred from these properties? It just seems strange that when I deploy to the server the ConnectionString property automatically gets deployed too under the "Configuration Manager" section in my screen shot suggesting it too needs to be bound to a "SSIS Environmental Variable".

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213214.aspx
>In general, if you are deploying a package using the package deployment model, you should use configurations instead of parameters.
When you deploy a package that contains parameters using the package deployment model and then execute the package, the parameters are not called during execution. If the package contains package parameters and expressions within the package use the parameters, the resulting values are applied at runtime. If the package contains project parameters, the package execution may fail.

Comment: I'm using the project deployment model. I think the answer to my question is that the ServerName and InitialCatalog properties that are bound to "SSIS Environmental Variables" will overwrite the design value in the ConnectionString property (even though it is still automatically deployed to the server and not actually configured/used).

Answer (score 0):

I tested several combinations of ConnectionString, InitialCatalog and ServerName. It looks like servername (DataSource) and initialcatalog have to be in the connection string and the initialcatalog has to have a value. If I left servername blank it worked as long as DataSource was in the connection string.